# Canvas Misaligned?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, rect

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsdIhyLKgjc and wrote this code:

```
public class DrawRect : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    public RectTransform rect;

    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;

    void Start () {
        rect.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition), out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) {
                startPos = hit.point;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            rect.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton (0)) {
            if (!rect.gameObject.activeInHierarchy) {
                rect.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            }
            endPos = Input.mousePosition;

            Vector3 squareStart = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (startPos);
            squareStart.z = 0f;

            Vector3 center = (squareStart + endPos / 2f);

            rect.position = center;

            float sizeX = Mathf.Abs (squareStart.x - endPos.x);
            float sizeY = Mathf.Abs (squareStart.y - endPos.y);

            rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (sizeX, sizeY);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem being that whenever I use it, it's misaligned. The scale is correct but the startpos and endpos are always 1/3 of the screen too far up and a bit to the right. Otherwise the endpos follows my mouse perfectly, staying misaligned to my actual mouse.

Any help with finding out the problem is greatly appreciated.

If I explained the problem poorly, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you asking your question here when the answer is verbatim in the tutorial you linked?

```
 Vector3 center = (squareStart + endPos / 2f);
```

Division takes precedence over the brackets.

```
 Vector3 center = (squareStart + endPos) / 2f;
```